# Tkinter: How to convert a tuple from listbox to list?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, tuples

I am trying to create a list from a list of items in a listbox. However, I am getting a tuple in return instead of an actual list. Here is an example of what I am talking about, please take a look:

```
from tkinter import*

root=Tk()

mylistbox=Listbox(root,width=60,height=10)
mylistbox.pack()

for items in range(0,11):
    mylistbox.insert(END,items)
list_of_numbers = []

list_of_numbers.append(mylistbox.get(0, END))

print(list_of_numbers)
print(list(list_of_numbers))

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]
```

Desired output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: `list(list_of_numbers[0])`.

Comment: @petezurich The edit to the title did not help anything. This question is actually more related to Python than it is to tkinter anyway. If any change would be made it would be to remove tkinter from the title.

Comment: @martineau can you tell me how editing the tile has made anything more clear than it was before? I find that to be an unnecessary edit.

Comment: @Mike: You asking a FAQ—because some redundancy was removed. See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) Speaking of which, don't you have something better to do than critiquing others edits--like answering questions?

Comment: @martineau that post also says we should trust the tags. I would then say `Tkinter` should be removed along with `Python` and the question should reflect the problem. Something like `convert tuple to list`. It does not matter that the tuple is created from `get()` used on a `listbox`. Thanks for the link though I will add it to my list of useful links.

Comment: @MiKe: Feel free to edit the title yourself—the OP can always reject it. FWIW, I sometimes leave one or two tags in to give the title by itself a little more context, but one of my pet peeves is with the vast number of folks putting the language tag into their question titles—although I realize it's just human nature and being done by relatively new users of the site who don't understand the tagging system in place.

Comment: @martineau I to have some pet peeves also and I do try to be professional about it. I tend to follow the paradigm that one should not edit unless it is improving the question/answer. (including readability edits). I tend to lean towards "if you are going to edit it then simplify it as much as you can" for titles, though this might not be everyone's cup of tea.

Comment: @Mike: Whatever. My own rule-of-thumb is whether it improves the question being asked or not, in my opinion—sometime by even a small amount.

Comment: @martineau I am not arguing with you about it. Just stating how I like to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the tuple created by `mylistbox.get(0, END)` to add each element of the tuple to a list instead of appending the tuple to the list directly.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

mylistbox = tk.Listbox(root,width=60,height=10)
mylistbox.pack()

for items in range(0,11):
    mylistbox.insert("end", items)
list_of_numbers = []

for item in mylistbox.get(0, "end"):
    list_of_numbers.append(item)

print(list_of_numbers)

root.mainloop()
```

You can also use `list()` directly on the results of `mylistbox.get(0, "end")` to get the same results as above and it becomes a convenient one liner:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

mylistbox = tk.Listbox(root,width=60,height=10)
mylistbox.pack()

for items in range(0,11):
    mylistbox.insert("end", items)

list_of_numbers = list(mylistbox.get(0, "end"))

print(list_of_numbers)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Yeah, that'd do it. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the list contains a tuple and that tuple is having elements:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

You need to iterate over the list and then over the tuple to extract each element and append them to list. Check out the below code:

```
from tkinter import*

root=Tk()

mylistbox=Listbox(root,width=60,height=10)
mylistbox.pack()

for items in range(0,11):
    mylistbox.insert(END,items)
list_of_numbers = []

list_of_numbers.append(mylistbox.get(0, END))

print(list_of_numbers)
mylist = []
for number in list_of_numbers[0]:
    mylist.append(number)
print(mylist)

root.mainloop()
```

Output :

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: You are doing extra work with `mylist` as it is not needed at all. If you want to iterate you can simply append each item to `list_of_numbers` or you can use `list()` directly which is probably the cleanest option here.

Comment: It's just to simplify the explanation. There is a lot of fancy coding you can find to work around the same problem. I wanted to explain in simple terms.

Comment: But you are not simplifying the example. In fact you are making it more complicated than it needs to be. One does not need to iterate over the list and then the tuple if you just create the list in the correct way in the first place. Really the simplest solution is actually a one liner here. `list_of_numbers = list(mylistbox.get(0, "end"))`.